# I create menu in Python but get eror

Tags: python

I get error after debugging.
The error is ("NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined).
Can help me with this error?

```
ans=True
while ans:
    print("""
    1.Add a Student
    2.Delete a Student
    3.Look Up Student Record
    4.Exit/Quit
    """)
    ans=raw_input("What would you like to do? ")
    if ans=="1":
      print("\nStudent Added")
    elif ans=="2":
      print("\n Student Deleted")
    elif ans=="3":
      print("\n Student Record Found")
    elif ans=="4":
      print("\n Goodbye") 
      ans = None
    else:
       print("\n Not Valid Choice Try again")
```

Comment: `raw_input` is not in Python3, just use `input` instead

Comment: Your learning materials are Python 2, but you're using Python 3. Python 2 has been deprecated; learn from something more up-to-date.